# Subscriber method vs event

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, thread-safety

I have noticed a new tendency in .NET 4.0, specifically in potentially multi-threaded scenarios, which is avoiding events, and providing subscriber methods instead.

For example, [System.Threading.Tasks.Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) and `Task<TResult>` have [ContinueWith()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) methods instead of a Completed or Finished event. Another example is [System.Threading.CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx): it has a [Register()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.register%28VS.100%29.aspx) method instead of a CancellationRequested event.

While Task.ContinueWith() is logical because it allows for easy task chaining (would not be so elegant with events), and that it also allows `Task<TResult>` to inherit from `Task` (because this way, `Task<TResult>` can provide appropriate overloads, which would not be possible for an event: if you have an event EventHandler Finished in Task, all you can do is create *another* event, say, event `EventHandler<TaskResultEventArgs>` Finished in `Task<TResult>`, which is not very nice), but I cannot find the same explanation for CancellationToken.Register().

So, what are the disadvantages of events in similar scenarios? Should I also follow this pattern? To clarify, which one of the below should I choose? When should I prefer one against the other?

```
public event EventHandler Finished;

// or

public IDisposable OnFinished(Action continuation)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: thanks, I didn't notice that my angel brackets needed some escaping.

Comment: UI events etc can be posted using the UI message queue and can potentially be really slow/heavy compared to using a delegate or a simple Task..

Comment: @Barfieldmv: Action call could be posted using the same technique with Invoke/BeginInvoke to the UI thread. It's not the difference.

Comment: @Ivan learn something new every day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one advantage of using subscriber methods is that you have the ability to easily specify the thread your delegate will be executed on. See [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321953.aspx) of CancellationToken.Register().

Upd: Well, actually you can specify the synchronization context your delegate will be posted to.

You are right about the tendency. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx) in MSDN Magazine states the following:

> New components shouldn’t use the
>   event-based asynchronous pattern. The
>   Visual Studio asynchronous Community
>   Technology Preview (CTP) includes a
>   document describing the task-based
>   asynchronous pattern, in which
>   components return Task and
>   Task objects instead of
>   raising events through
>   SynchronizationContext. Task-based
>   APIs are the future of asynchronous
>   programming in .NET.

And the [document](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19957) the article refers to says

> Initiation and completion of an
>   asynchronous operation in the TAP are
>   represented by a single method, and
>   thus there is only one method to name.
>   This is in contrast to the
>   IAsyncResult pattern, or APM pattern,
>   where BeginMethodName and
>   EndMethodName methods are required,
>   and in contrast to the event-based
>   asynchronous pattern, or EAP, where a
>   MethodNameAsync is required in
>   addition to one or more events, event
>   handler delegate types, and
>   EventArg-derived types.

And indeed, taking care of one thing instead of many is kind of good. But this is more of advantage of TAP over EAP, not the advantage of subscriber methods.

Comment: That makes sense. Methods (subscriber methods) are more flexible than events, and are also less problematic (e.g. event-related memory leaks). In the other hand, methods feel like a step backwards, because the programmer also has to implement a list storing the callbacks, worry about thread-safety of the callback list. So it would appear that in general, events are still preferable over plain _subscriber_ methods (not talking about EAP here), and subscriber methods are usually not worth it (except when specifying special callback behavior, for instance). Thanks for the answer!